# "in the cross hairs" usage

Tags: idioms

I heard the following speech in the movie:

> No, you should see *Spaceballs.* It's, like, really funny. 'Cause
>   it's, like, a spoof of *Star Wars,* but it's also, like, a spoof
>   of, like, different sci-fi movies. Like, *Planet of the Apes* and
>   *Star Trek.* Like... But it, like, really puts, like, *Star
>   Wars* in its crosshairs.

Idiom "in the cross hairs" means "in a position to be criticized or attacked", for example:

> Her independence put her in the cross hairs of some local
>   politicians

So I guess that the last sentence from the movie could be said as:
"It (meaning SpaceBalls) puts Start Wars in a position to be criticized by it(meaning Spaceballs)".

I am wondering whether "by it" is required in a sentence like this? Can I say

> It puts StarWars in the cross hairs

Comment: [General Reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crosshair)

Comment: I don't know if this is a question about the idiom "in the cross hairs," which is a metaphoric reference to a telescopic gun sight, or ("I am wondering whether 'by it' is required...") if the question is really about ambiguous pronoun reference.  Either way, it's ELL-y, I think.

Comment: Yes, "in the cross-hairs" is a reference to a gun sight, meaning "targeted".  Only in certain cases does it mean "targeted for criticism".  A little hard to guess the intended meaning here, but I'd probably go with "Spaceballs really does a good job of parodying Star Wars."

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by *a sentence like this* in *I am wondering whether "by it" is required in a sentence like this?* Do you mean the original (*But it, like, really puts, like, Star Wars in its crosshairs*)? Or do you mean your paraphrase: *"It (meaning SpaceBalls) puts Start Wars in a position to be criticized by it(meaning Spaceballs)"*? Or do you mean: *It puts StarWars in the cross hairs*. -- Note that we normally use *I put the book on the table*, not *I put the book on the table by me.* -- Also, one use of the passive voice is to avoid talking about the "agent" explicitly.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Actually what confuses me is *its* word in "But it, like, really puts, like, Star Wars in *its* crosshairs.". I guess it refers to Spaceballs, not Star Wars and wanted to check whether my assumption is correct and also whether it's OK to get rid of *its* in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "in the cross hairs" is perhaps more general than "in a position to be criticized or attacked". The cross-hairs refers to the vertical and horizontal lines in the telescopic sight of a rifle. So when somebody is in the cross hairs, it means that they are a target for criticism, blame, or ill-treatment of some kind. See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_crosshairs.

One can put oneself in the cross-hairs, for example by expressing an unpopular view (as in your second example), or somebody else can be targeting you.

In your first example, the intended meaning is probably that Spaceballs is targeting Star Wars for some sort of lampoon. So your final statement "It puts Star Wars in the cross hairs" is a valid and correct use of the idiom.

I can't help thinking that the script writer that wrote this example had the archetypal Sci-Fi film watcher in the cross hairs as he wrote those (semi-literate) words....

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but I am wondering whether or not you've answered the OP's question - which, admittedly, I'm not sure about either.